# Adding another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I add another multidimensional array to an already existing array.

```
$args = array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3);
```

Then I want to add 'd'=>4 to the already set array. I tried:

```
$args[] = array('d'=>4);
```

But I end up getting

```
Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [c] => 3 [0] => Array ( [d] => 4 ) )
```

Instead of

```
Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [c] => 3 [0] => [d] => 4 )
```

What is the correct way to achieve this result?

Comment: Are you looking to explicitly set [d]=>4 or did you want a more general solution?

Comment: These arrays do not appear to be multidimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example that only works if you want to *explicitly* set key `d` to `4`. If you want a more general solution, see the other answers. Since the other answers did not mention the explicit solution, I thought I would.

You tried this:

```
$args[] = array('d'=>4);
```

What this did was add the array `['d'=>4]` as a new entry to the existing `$args` array. If you really wanted to set the value of `$args['d']` to `4` then you can do it directly:

```
$args['d'] = 4;
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**
This is an explicit answer. It will overwrite key `d` if it already exists. It is not useful for adding new entries to the array since you'd have to manually do so. This is *only* to be used if you just want to set one element no matter what and be done. *Do not* use this if you need a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge($myArray, array('d' => 1234))` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$args = array('foo' => 1);
$args = array_merge($args, array('bar'=>2));
```

This will make `$args`

```
array => [
   'foo' => 1,
   'bar' => 2
]
```

Comment: array_merge($args, array('d' => 4)); gave me Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [c] => 3 ) , so it didnt seem to add it.

Comment: It does not modify your original array.  If you want $args to still be it you'll need to do `$args = array_merge($args, array('d' => 4))`

Comment: Oh I see you need to add it to the variable

Comment: @VivianKennedy yup!  Glad you got it.  :D